# UnsatisfiedLinkError when running strazzere`s anti-emulator from git hub

Tags: android, android-ndk, emulation, ndk-build

I want to add anti emulation to my android app, for this i have selected [this](https://github.com/strazzere/anti-emulator) git hub repo as a startup. I download the zip from repo and tried to run it, but it throws UnsatisfiedLinkError  while loading library file. here is the stack trace.

```
2019-05-22 18:55:38.808 4346-4365/diff.strazzere.anti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
    Process: diff.strazzere.anti, PID: 4346
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/diff.strazzere.anti-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/diff.strazzere.anti-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/diff.strazzere.anti-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libanti.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562)
        at diff.strazzere.anti.emulator.FindEmulator.<clinit>(FindEmulator.java:63)
        at diff.strazzere.anti.emulator.FindEmulator.hasKnownDeviceId(FindEmulator.java:159)
        at diff.strazzere.anti.MainActivity.isQEmuEnvDetected(MainActivity.java:44)
        at diff.strazzere.anti.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:29)
```

crashes here

```
static {
        // This is only valid for arm
        System.loadLibrary("anti");
    }
```

I have commented these line from build.gradle. Uncommenting these line throws

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: "Task to run ndk-build") {
//    commandLine 'ndk-build'
    commandLine project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath + '/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni/').absolutePath
 }

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild }

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: "Task to run ndk-build clean") {
    commandLine 'ndk-build', 'clean'
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'
```

Un commenting these line throws

```
 18:59:56.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build''
    18:59:56.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
    18:59:56.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

**Update** Running with --stacktracke

```
Executing tasks: [:AntiEmulator:assembleDebug]


> Configure project :AntiEmulator
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :AntiEmulator:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :AntiEmulator:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :AntiEmulator:ndkBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':AntiEmulator:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build''

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':AntiEmulator:ndkBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:232)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:209)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:356)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WindowsProcessLauncher.start(WindowsProcessLauncher.java:22)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:97)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:70)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build" (in directory "C:\Users\username\Downloads\anti-emulator-master\AntiEmulator"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    ... 9 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
7 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 6 up-to-date
```

Comment: Unless that has changed, you should be using `ndk-build.cmd` on Windows systems (note the file extension).

Comment: tried but same result

Comment: Then I suggest you build again with `--stacktrace` (or `--info`) as the error message suggests to get more detailed information.

Comment: Updated with stacktrace. it says "the system cannot find the file specified" which file exactly ?